# Codeigniter undefined property, can't load model into controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter 3, I've seen similar problems on this website and tried every permutation of the solutions offered to no avail.

I am trying to create a table via the cli with CodeIgniter. But this results in an error I just cant seem to figure out, any help is greatly appreciated!

Model:

```
<?php
class App_model extends CI_Model {
  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
  }
  public function create_table(){
    $this->drop();
    $sql='CREATE TABLE app (
      id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      text text NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );';
    $this->db->query($sql);
  }
  public function drop(){
    $this->db->query('DROP TABLE app');
  }
}
?>
```

Controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class App extends CI_Controller {
    public function __contruct(){
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->model('App_model');
    }
    public function test(){
      $this->App_model->create_table();
    }
}
?>
```

Terminal:

```
asergey91:~/workspace $ php index.php App test

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity:    Notice
Message:     Undefined property: App::$App_model
Filename:    /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/App.php
Line Number: 10

Backtrace:
        File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/App.php
        Line: 10
        Function: _error_handler

        File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
        Line: 292
        Function: require_once



Fatal error: Call to a member function create_table() on a non-object in /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/App.php on line 10

Call Stack:
    0.0003     255192   1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php:0
    0.0010     317824   2. require_once('/home/ubuntu/workspace/system/core/CodeIgniter.php') /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php:292
    0.0171    1549776   3. call_user_func_array:{/home/ubuntu/workspace/system/core/CodeIgniter.php:514}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/system/core/CodeIgniter.php:514
    0.0171    1550040   4. App->test() /home/ubuntu/workspace/system/core/CodeIgniter.php:514


A PHP Error was encountered

Severity:    Error
Message:     Call to a member function create_table() on a non-object
Filename:    /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/App.php
Line Number: 10

Backtrace:
```

Comment: Database loaded in auto load?

Comment: Why? If i have $this->load->database();

Comment: Is your model filename ucfirst ? `App_model.php` not  `app_model.php`

Comment: OK no need... Your file name start with capital letter `App_model.php`  or small letter `app_letter.php`?

Comment: model name is not capitalized its app_model.php

Comment: I am following the conventions listed here
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

Comment: codeigniter's documentation moved to http://www.codeigniter.com

Comment: Actualy, [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/). ;)

Comment: Test it friend?? Still error?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/0nmokxo.png, renamed error still presists

Comment: correct spelling of your construct function in your controller first. :)

Comment: yep, and that typo took us only like an hour to figure out. =) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments : Your controller's file name must start with an uppercase. In your case, App_model.php. 
See http://codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html

> changed filenaming convention (class file names now must be Ucfirst
>   and everything else in lowercase).

So change `app_model.php` to `App_model.php`

EDIT :

Also, In your controller, Watch the caps : `$this->load->model('app_model')` and `$this->app_model->...` . Don't use any caps unless it's in your filenames.

Remove the closing php tags.

And in the end, you have a typo `function __contruct` instead of `function __construct()`

Comment: i.imgur.com/0nmokxo.png, renamed error still presists

Comment: @SergeyAndreev, In your controller, call `$this->app_model->...` . Don't use any caps unless it's in your filenames.

Comment: forgot the load call, sorry.  `$this->load->model('app_model');`

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/xAboDsp.png, I did say that I tried every permutation =). Still no luck.

Comment: Also remove your closing php tags `?>` from all the files you've created so far.

Comment: ok, I actually put them there just to see if it would change anything =).
But yeah: http://i.imgur.com/U04l6CD.png.
That didn't solve it

Comment: Maybe its something simpler? I mainly work with ruby on rails and this is a first time in a long time I set up PHP.

Comment: I don't see what can be simplier than closing php tags ^^
I'm running out of ideas. Sorry :(. I compared with one of my models, Except I have no `load->database()` We have pretty much the same thing. I'll delete my answer later.

Comment: @SergeyAndreev Oh, one last thing, I also have that header in my models : `defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');` and you don't.

Comment: Then sorry, Good luck with that. I'll follow your case, I'm curious to see what is it.

Comment: It'll probably be something really dumb, it always is =)

Comment: I reproduced your issue, and I just moved the load function inside the test() function and it worked. I don't know why it dodn't inside the constructor I do that all the time.

Comment: @SergeyAndreev I FOUND IT ! You are right, it was really dumb. You have a typo : `__contruct()` instead of `__construct()`. So the constructor was never called and the model never loaded.

Comment: LOL, of course it is..... Well... I just reassured myself that I'm not very smart =). Thanks for your help man.

Comment: Good work bro me was busy didn't chk the response vote for u bro

Answer (score 1):

In `Codignitor 3` you need to use first letter capital for your file like:

```
app_model.php
```

Should be:

```
App_model.php
```

Comment: i.imgur.com/0nmokxo.png, renamed error still presists